# Silverlight Data Grid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

Is there any way to animate a row of my datagrid on a property change??

I want the row background to flicker when one of the values in the row changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-template the "Template" property in your DataGrid.RowStyle.  Add an element that encapsulates the elements of the row, and animate that when you add an item.  It will be a bit of work, but it certainly is possible

```
<Style x:Key="AnimatedDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="data:DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="data:DataGridRow">
               ...
```